# i define muntiple usestate my only one is working

Tags: next.js, hook

[image]

[image]

here i define 3 usestate, my firsr use state of boola is working but my func and func2 are not , displays are not setting as acc to initial use state values.

Comment: Please don't post codes as screenshot. Paste your codes in your question and format it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put the 'func' in brackets.

So your code should be like this.

```
<div style={{display: func}} id={styles1.icon}>
...
```